# AttributeError in my django rest project

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
       owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
       highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippet-highlight', format='html')

       class Meta:
            model = Snippet
            fields = ('url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner',
              'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
```

it is my SnippetSerializer class and also defined

```
owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
```

i grts an error that
**AttributeError at /snippets/3/highlight/
'Snippet' object has no attribute 'highlighted'**
could you solve it?

```
class SnippetHighlight(generics.GenericAPIView):
queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
renderer_classes = (renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer,)
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    snippet = self.get_object()
    return Response(snippet.highlighted)
```

it is my SnippetHighlight view

Comment: In the serializer you refer to a `highlight` field, the attribute error indicates that there is no attribute named `highlighted`, note the `d` at the end. My guess is that you are attempting to access the incorrect attribute somewhere else in the code, maybe on the detail view

Comment: class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    #permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

class SnippetHighlight(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = (renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = self.get_object()
        return Response(snippet.highlighted)

Comment: Please don't post code in comments; edit the question to add your update.

Answer (score 0):

In the serializer you refer to a `highlight` field, the attribute error indicates that there is no attribute named `highlighted`, note the `d` at the end. My guess is that you are attempting to access the incorrect attribute somewhere else in the code.

After response comment:

It looks like the issue is in the return value

```
return Response(snippet.highlighted)
```

The snippet model has no attribute `highlighted`, from the serializer I asume this should be:

```
return Response(snippet.highlight)
```

Comment: i updated my SnippetHighlight view. still i gets same error

Comment: Just double check that you are not referring to the incorrect version(highlighted) somewhere in your codebase